# IndexedDB Convert Sync to Async

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

actually working on a big web application that use localStorage and we need to migrate to IndexedDB, my challenge is how to change my synchronous service that set/get localStorage values, to an service that use indexeddb asynchronously without change all appilation calls to my service ?

i would not change each call to a new promise call with .then(....), want just a minimal change of my service.

thank you

Comment: You can use JsStore for such a change. Basically you just need to define your db schema and after that you can write simple sql like qry for db manipulation. JsStore link - http://jsstore.net/

Comment: @UjjwalKumarGupta thanks, i don't ask about an external library, i have 123 synchronous calls to my storage service, the solution is to change all my 123 calls with a promise to support asynchronously indexeddb calls.
My question is, is there a solution to change just my service code without changing all my code

Comment: I think in that case, promise will be the best option to use if you are going for plain indexeddb.